# Hilbert space identification

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

[image]

I am totally lost so can someone please explain how to identify $l^2(H)$ with $H\otimes l^2$?

Comment: A natural isomorphism is given by map induced on the tensor product $\mathcal H\otimes\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ the bilinear map $\mathcal H\times\ell^2(\mathbb N)\to\ell^2(\mathcal H)$ given by $(\psi\in\mathcal H,(a_n)\in\ell^2(\mathbb N) )\mapsto (a_n\psi)\in\ell^2(\mathcal H)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define, for $x\in H$ and $a\in\ell^2$,
$$
W(x\otimes a)=(a_n x)_n\in\ell^2(H)
$$
and extend by linearity. We have
\begin{align}
\Big\|W\Big(\sum_{m=1}^Mx_m\otimes a_m\Big)\Big\|^2
&=\Big\langle \sum_{m=1}^M(a_m(n)x_m)_n,\sum_{m=1}^M(a_m(n)x_m)_n\Big\rangle \\[0.3cm]
&= \sum_{m,h=1}^M\big\langle \big(a_m(n)x_m\big)_n,\big(a_h(n)x_h\big)_n\big\rangle\\[0.3cm]
&=\sum_{m,h=1}^M \sum_na_m(n)\overline{a_h(n)}\,\langle x_m,x_h\rangle\\[0.3cm]
&=\sum_{m,h=1}^M \langle a_m,a_h\rangle\,\langle x_m,x_h\rangle\\[0.3cm]
&=\sum_{m,h=1}^M \langle x_m\otimes a_m,x_h\otimes a_h\rangle\\[0.3cm]
&=\Big\|\sum_{m=1}^Mx_m\otimes a_m\Big\|^2. 
\end{align}
So $W$ is isometric on a dense set and thus it extends to an isometry. If $\{g_m\}$ is a basis for $H$ and $\{e_n\}$ is the canonical basis for $\ell^2$, it is easy to check that the elements $$
f_{n,m}=\{(0,\ldots,0,g_m,0,\ldots),
$$where the nonzero entry is the $n^{\rm th}$ one, as for $n\in\mathbb N$ and each element in the basis $\{g_m\}$, is a basis for $\ell^2(H)$. Then we have
$$
W(g_m\otimes e_n)=f_{n,m}. 
$$
This shows that $W$ has dense range. Being an isometry its range is closed, so $W$ is onto, and thus a unitary.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.